# Communicating with a unix filter process in Python

Tags: python, django, ipc, subprocess

I am writing a Python program that needs to clean many small strings using an external unix program which works as a filter. Currently, I create a new subprocess for each string I want to clean:

```
import subprocess
def cleanstring(s):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/filter','-n'],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    out, err = proc.communicate(s)
    assert not err
    return out
```

Obviously, this approach is grossly inefficient. What would be an efficient way to start the filter subprocess and communicate with it via stdin/stdout for as long as needed?

I've been looking into using [Python Queues](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) to implement this, but they may be an overkill for this. The code will be called from a Django view on a non-threaded web server, so it will only be a single thread calling it multiple times.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the external program do? Is it easier to do the same thing in Python?

Comment: No, it isn't. The filter I want to call is detex, which removes TeX and LaTeX markup from text. Properly implementing this in Python would require writing/testing/maintaining a lex parser for TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: OK. Do the small strings ever include a newline? Could you feed a batch to the subprocess, get the results, and split on newlines?

Comment: Batch processing would complicate the structure of the actual program. I want the processing by detex to take place at the point where it is required. It already works ok with the implementation I described. I just want to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't measured it, then it's not a performance problem, much less "grossly inefficient".

That said, you can communicate with a subprocess like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen('bc', shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

 for i in range(10):
     p.stdin.write('%s*2\n' % (i,))
     res = p.stdout.readline()
     if res:
         print "vtrip says %s*2 is %s" % (i, res.strip())
         p.stdin.flush()
```

This prints the doubles of 0-9, as returned by the same bc process. Should be easy to adapt to detex (the main thing would be to handle flush correctly so one end doesn't stuck waiting for the other).

That's the communicating part. As for the "long running inside Django" might not be a good idea. Queues might indeed be too much.

And task queues like Celery et al are for tasks to be handled independently, not for the same long running service handling each one.

Maybe run some small python daemon on the side, keeping the filter process open and handling requests from Django for it? Are we talking about heavy load, or something internal, for, say, 100 users per day? You might not need much synchronisation besides some crude locking at all.

Comment: I was worried about how you would flush the buffering to ensure the string is handled.  Your code shows that this is actually pretty easy: `p.stdin.flush()`  So +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your current code is the best solution.  Under Linux, starting up a process isn't really that expensive, and you have neatly encapsulated the problem.  And you are directly starting the `filter` program, so you don't have the overhead of starting up a shell to run it.

Also, I am rather worried about caching.  Suppose you do get the `filter` program running in the background, reading and writing named pipes or whatever.  How will you be sure that each string you push through comes out immediately?  How will you flush the pipeline to synchronize the output with the input?

Have you measured the load on your Django server and found this to be a problem?  If you have measured the performance, please share the numbers.  I'd be surprised if you actually have a problem.